# How to get the transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be the transformation of the xy-plane that reflects each vector through the x-axis and then doubles the vector's length. If A is the 2*2 matrix such that [image]
then A=[image]. I don't know how to get this answer.Please help me, thank you.

Comment: What does the notation $\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remember the first week of linear algebra when they told you that linear transforms are the type where $f(ax + by)$ = $a\cdot f(x) + b \cdot f(y)$ ?  Well that's how you find the matrix that represents a linear transform.

Suppose $e_1=(1, 0)$ is your unit vector on the x-axis and $e_2=(0, 1)$ is your unit vector on the y-axis.  Then any vector $(x, y)$ is the same as $xe_1 + ye_2$.

So your transform is $T(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}) = \text{flipped then scaled}$.  Assume for now that it's a linear transform, so that means it has a matrix.

$T(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}) = T(xe_1 + ye_2) = xT(e_1) + yT(e_2) = \begin{bmatrix} T(e_1) & T(e_2) \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$

So what happens to $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ when you flip it and double it?  You get $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
What happens to $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ when you flip and double it?  You get $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$.

So $T(\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

reflections and scalings are linear operations, hence so it their composition. So $T$ is linear.

The nice thing about linear operators is that their behaviour is completely specified by their behaviour on a basis.

The vectors $e_1=(1,0)^T$ and $e_2=(0,1)^T$ form a basis for the plane.

In this case we have $T e_1 = 2e_1$ and $Te_2 = -2 e_2$. Hence we have $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 &  0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$.